# Query builder in Laravel - 2 columns.id foreigns key in a Users.name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem in my project

I'm trying to do a query with the table "Asignaciones", this table save the records for students and teachers asignations. (The teachers can comment the works of students and can see only the students that are asigned) The principal problem is that all the users is on the same table and when i try to return a names just have one.

[image]

[image]

```
$asignaciones = DB::table('asignaciones')
        ->join('users as students','students.id',
                '=','asignaciones.id_student')
        ->join('users as teachers','teachers.id',
               '=','asignaciones.id_teacher')
        ->select('asignaciones.id','students.name',
                  'teachers.name')->get();

return $asignaciones;
```

[image]

I need to get two names (Maybe changing the column name like a users table) to show in a table

Thanks for your time and answers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define unique aliases in your select clause for student name and teacher name

```
->select('asignaciones.id','students.name as student_name','teachers.name as teacher_name');
```

Right now single alias `name` is returned for teacher and student name in the returned result set, object cannot have 2 keys with same name so one of the names got override while laravel maps the DB result to object or collection of objects

Comment: Thank you! Finally my query works fine:
$asignaciones = DB::table('asignaciones')
            ->join('users as students','students.id',
                    '=','asignaciones.id_student')
            ->join('users as teachers','teachers.id',
                   '=','asignaciones.id_teacher')
            ->select('asignaciones.id','students.name as student_name',
                      'teachers.name as teacher_name')->get();